# How to add widgets button next to every row of a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, widget, ipywidgets

I want to add button to every row next to the dataframe.

This is my code right now.

```
  PRO_name_list = []
  c.execute("SELECT pro_name FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY pro_name ASC")
  for row in c:
    PRO_name_list.append(row[0])

  PRO_price_list = []
  c.execute("SELECT pro_price FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY pro_name ASC")
  for row in c:
    PRO_price_list.append(row[0])

  PRO_id_list = []
  c.execute("SELECT pro_id FROM PRODUCT ORDER BY pro_name ASC")
  for row in c:
    PRO_id_list.append(row[0])

  d = []
  for names in PRO_name_list:
    for row in PRO_id_list:
      if PRO_name_list.index(names) == PRO_id_list.index(row):
       d.append([names, "${0:.1f}".format(PRO_price_list[PRO_name_list.index(names)])]) 
       HOM_rowHBox = widgets.HBox([HOM_addtocart_button])
       display(widgets.VBox([HOM_rowHBox]))

  df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=None)
  display(df.style
       .hide_index()
       .hide_columns())
```

Output

[image: Output]

What I want to do:

[image]

I don't know how I can achieve that. And I cannot find similar questions that I understand on Stack overflow. So, I want someone to tell me an approach for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a more reproducible example? But I think you can use a single display using `display(HBox(df_styled, buttons))`. Store the widgets.VBox([HOM_rowHBox]) in a variable (maybe buttons) and df.style.hide_index().hide_columns() in another variable (maybe df_styled) and then display both at the same time.

Comment: I think i solved this issue already, thanks for helping